# Extend Vuetify components in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to extend a vuetify component with some default props set in TypeScript. In JavaScript it worked perfectly but I can't figure out how to extend the components in TS. Here is the code for the Component in JS:

```js
import { VTextField } from 'vuetify/lib'

export default {
  name: "my-text-field",
  extends: VTextField,
  props: {
      "hide-details": {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
      },
      outlined: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
      },
      dense: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
      },
      "single-line": {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
      },
      color: {
        type: String,
        default: "secondary"
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to do that add in the tsconfig.json

```
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["vuetify"]
  }
}
```

Now just extend the needful component.

```
<script lang="ts">
import { VTextField } from 'vuetify/lib'

import { Component,  Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component({})
export default class TextField extends VTextField {
    @Prop({default: 'auto'}) private hideDetails!: boolean|string;
    @Prop({default: true}) private outlined!: boolean;
    @Prop({default: true}) private dense!: boolean
    @Prop({default: true}) private singleLine!: boolean;
    @Prop({default: 'secondary'}) private color!: string
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you use Vuetify 3, it become `import {…} from "vuetify/components"

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution by peeking into the VTextArea component of Vuetify. Here's my solution:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
//@ts-ignore
import VTextField from 'vuetify/lib/components/VTextField/VTextField'

// Create Base Mixins and Define Custom Properties
const base = Vue.extend({ mixins: [VTextField] })
export default base.extend({
  name: "my-text-field",
  props: {
      hideDetails: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
      },
      outlined: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
      },
      dense: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
      },
      singleLine: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
      },
      color: {
        type: String,
        default: "secondary"
      }
  }
})
```

Comment: +1 For your answer. I experienced a slightly different problem, but your answer pointed me in the right direction. 
Cannot read property 'props' of undefined when I tried to extend the Vuetify Pagination component to make it work with NuxtJS. This only seemed to happen when I build the project but not in production.

Initially I registered the component Globally const VPagination = Vue.component('VPagination'); and then replaced it with 

// @ts-ignore
import VPagination from 'vuetify/lib/components/VPagination/VPagination'; which solved my issue. 

Thanks.

Comment: @Elitmiar can you post your solution? I have the same problem with NuxtJs and a Vuetify component. Thanks

Comment: I used it this way in nuxt:

    // @ts-ignore
    import VBtn from 'vuetify/lib/components/VBtn/VBtn'

    VBtn.options.props.ripple.default = false

Answer (score 1):

hope this works for you:

```
import {Vue, Component, Prop} from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { VIcon, VTextField} from 'vuetify/lib'


interface Item {
    text: string;
    complete: boolean;
}

@Component({
    name: 'TodoItem',
    components: {
        'v-icon': VIcon,
         'v-text-field': VTextField
    }
})
export default class TodoItem extends Vue {

    @Prop(Object) public item!: Item;
    @Prop(Number) public index!: number;
    @Prop(Number) public editingId!: number;

    public editingContent = 'nihao';

    public edit() {
        this.$emit('on-edit', this.index)
    }

    public save() {
        alert('k');
    }


    protected render() {
        return (
            <li>
                {this.editingId === this.index ?
                    (<div>
                        {/* tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length */}
                        <v-text-field v-model={this.editingContent} append-icon={'mdi-close'} placeholder={this.item.text} on-click:append={this.save}/>
                        {/*<v-text-field><v-icon color={'red'} slot={'append'}>mdi-close</v-icon></v-text-field>*/}
                    </div>)
                    : (<div>
                            <span>{this.item.text}</span>
                            <v-icon x-small={true} nativeOn-click={this.edit}>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
                        </div>)
                }
            </li>
        );
    }
}
```